# Sort the file with given string in linux

Tags: linux

I would like sort the line of file with given string for below example:

```
"104~Rahul~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded 
Fine</td>~<td></td>~<td></td>~Customer_files_are_loading_by_DMS_Team
104~Rahul_DWA~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded 
Fine</td>~<td></td>~<td></td>~Customer_files_are_loading_by_DMS_Team
104~Rahul_SFI~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded 
Fine</td>~<td></td>~<td></td>~Customer_files_are_loading_by_DMS_Team
104~Rahul_SFI~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded 
Fine</td>~<td></td>~<td></td>~Customer_files_are_loading_by_DMS_Team
15014~JVCanada~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td></td>~<td 
bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded 
Fine</td>~We_are_not_receiving_Cleared_file
10148~Kedar~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=RED>Not loaded</td>~<td bgcolor=RED>Not loaded</td>~<td></td>~NA
70169~Kedar~<td bgcolor=GREEN>Loaded Fine</td>~<td bgcolor=RED>Not loaded</td>~<td></td>~<td></td>~NA"
```

String should be if it's Not Loaded the line should come first and rest follows

Comment: may i know what you tried ?

Comment: Looks like `grep` is enough like `grep -v "Loaded Fine" ` then `grep "Loaded Fine"`

Comment: 1 st line --> 104~Rahul_DWA~Loaded Fine~Loaded Fine
2nd line ---> 10148~Kedar~Loaded Fine~Not loaded~Not loaded

I want check if line contain " Not loaded" then it should be first line

Comment: @AbdullahKhan so grep is your friend

Comment: can you tell the exact command to do so

Comment: `grep 'Not loaded' file; grep -v 'Not loaded' file`

Answer (score 0):

try running these in a single line:

`grep 'Not loaded' file; grep -v 'Not loaded' file`